# docker-compose - issue restarting single service

Tags: docker-compose

I am using docker-compose for a development project. I have 6 services defined in my docker compose file. I have been using the below script to rebuild the images whenever I make a change.

```
#!/bin/bash
# file: rebuild.sh
docker-compose down
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

I am looking for a way to reduce the build time as building and restarting all the services seems unnecessary as I am usually only changing one module. I see in the docker-compose docs you can run commands for individual services by specifying the service name after e.g. `docker-compose build myservice`.

In another terminal window I tried `docker-compose build myservice && docker-compose restart myservice` while leaving the other `./rebuild.sh` command open in the original terminal. In the `./rebuild.sh` terminal window I see all the initialization messages being reprinted to the stdout so I know it is restarting that service but the code changes aren't there. What am I doing wrong? I just want to rebuild and restart a single service.

Comment: You rebuild the image to feed container with data? Why don’t you mount volumes instead?

Comment: I know about bind volumes where you can point to your source code directory but I for simple projects I just wanted to know if there was a simple way to rebuild/restart a single service. Trying not to get too complicated.

Comment: Did you think about use arguments in your rebuild script? Something like ./rebuild.sh myservice. If you want to do that you can use $1 variable to read the name of your service received as parameter.

Comment: The docker-compose up and down commands don't take a service name as an argument. That's why I was trying to use docker-compose restart. I also tried docker-compose stop/start but it's effectively the same as restart.

Comment: Try docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --build myservice . Note that -d is for Detached mode, -d is for force recreation even is your code did not change, -build is for build your images before starting and at least the name of your service. Read more here https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/

Comment: That works! @Nico if you want to create an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Your welcome! I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --build myservice`

Note that:
-d is for Detached mode, 
-force-recreate will recreate containers even is your code did not change, 
-build is for build your images before starting containers. 
At least the name of your service.

Take a look [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up).